# Venn Diagram style grouping in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Ok. The title might be a little confusing but here is what I am trying to do

I have a series of natural numbers

```
var series = Enumerable.Range(1, 100)
```

Now I want to use `GroupBy` to put numbers into these 3 groups, Prime, Even, Odd

```
series.Select(number => {
                 var type = "";
                 if (MyStaticMethods.IsPrime(number)) 
                   {
                     Type = "prime";
                   }
                 else if (number % 2 == 0)
                   {
                      type = "Even";
                   }
                 else
                  {
                      type = "Odd";
                  }
                   return new { Type=type, Number = number };
               }).GroupBy(n => n.Type);
```

Now the above query will miss categorizing Prime numbers that are even or odd into both categories and they will just be in 'prime' group. Is there any way for the above select to yield multiple numbers?

I could try something like the following, but it requires an additional flattening of the sequence.

```
series.Select(number => {
                 var list = new List<int>();

                 if (MyStaticMethods.IsPrime(number)) 
                   {
                      list.Add(new { Type="prime", Number = number });
                   }
                 if (number % 2 == 0)
                   {
                      list.Add(new { Type="even", Number = number });
                   }
                 else
                  {
                      list.Add(new { Type="odd", Number = number });
                  }
                   return list;
               })
              .SelectMany(n => n)
            .GroupBy(n => n.Type);
```

The above code solves my issue, is there any better way that could make my code look more "functional" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use linq here, but you'll need to duplicate some values that can exist in different groups.  `GroupBy` only works for disjoint groups so you need a way to distinguish `2` the even number and `2` the prime number.  The approach you did is essentially what you need to do, but it could be done a little more efficiently.

You can define a set of categories that can help classify the numbers.  You don't necessarily need to define new classes to get this to work, but it helps to keep things clean and organized.

```
class Category<T>
{
    public Category(string name, Predicate<T> predicate)
    {
        Name = name;
        Predicate = predicate;
    }
    public string Name { get; }
    public Predicate<T> Predicate { get; }
}
```

Then to group the numbers, you'd do this:

```
var series = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
var categories = new[]
{
    new Category<int>("Prime", i => MyStaticMethods.IsPrime(i)),
    new Category<int>("Odd", i => i % 2 != 0),
    new Category<int>("Even", i => i % 2 == 0),
};
var grouped =
    from i in series
    from c in categories
    where c.Predicate(i)
    group i by c.Name;
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a good case to use Reactive Extensions, as you will avoid to duplicate values.

In the code below ,  "series" is parsed only once, because it's a hot source thanks to the Publish().
The actual parsing is done during the "Connect()".

```
using System.Reactive.Linq;

var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

var series= Observable.Range(1, 100).Publish();
series.Where(e => e % 2 == 0).Subscribe(e=>list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Even",e)));
series.Where(e => e % 2 == 1).Subscribe(e => list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Odd", e)));
series.Where(e => MyStaticMethods.IsPrime(e) ).Subscribe(e => list.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Prime", e)));
series.Connect();

var result = list.GroupBy(n => n.Key);
```